# failed to open stream: No route to host in /home/acucli/public_html/ihc-ws/payNow.php on line 17 PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I'm really in big trouble because of this bloody thing, it was working perfect for many days but now whenever i use SAOPClient using __doRequest function it gives me error and when i refresh the page many times then it start working fine.

Please find the full detail of error below.

```
 Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(https://-----WSDL/common_types.xsd) [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: No route to host in /home/acucli/public_html/ihc-ws/payNow.php on line 17

 Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://----/WSDL/common_types.xsd" in /home/acucli/public_html/ihc-ws/payNow.php on line 17

 Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'https://---/WSDL/common_types.xsd' in /home/acucli/public_html/ihc-ws/payNow.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home/acucli/public_html/ihc-ws/payNow.php(17): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://epaymen...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/acucli/public_html/ihc-ws/payNow.php on line 17
```

Could you please help me out why it's happening?

I have used ini_set( "soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0 ); already but it didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 1):

Usually "No route to host" is a standard OS message indicating that there is no route to hostname you are trying to establish connection to. In most cases this would mean you are not connected to the internet or your routing tables are messed up. Try `route` command on your shell and check that you have a proper default gateway.

Comment: Or maybe the remote host does not exist any more.

Comment: Problem is when i refresh the same page couple of times, it start working fine. there must be something else..

Comment: Can you access the same resource without PHP using your browser, or wget or any other utility? This is much more likely a network configuration issue than php / soap issue. PHP just forwards you the message it gets from operating system. If it starts/stops working at random, this could indicate and IP conflict. Did you assign IP address of the machine manually or using DHCP? Try changing IP address.